# Adding Options to Options Menu from Activity Class

Tags: android, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

How can I show the value in my `EditText` into an optionsMenu on `Button` click?

E.g. If I enter *abc* in `EditText` and then I press a `Button` (add `Button`), then I should be getting an optionsMenu with *abc* added into it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like? You might be better off looking through some tutorials.

Comment: So far, I took an editText and a button..i made a method for button called addition..nd declared the same in my xml file(onClick method) ..then in my addition method,I simply wrote that getText.toString stuff.and then i gave a condition that if(St.equals("abc")){  showOptionsMenu();  }  else { show a toast saying..user cnnt enter empty data  } ..I am really stuck..please can you solve the code for me..I would be really grateful :(

Comment: Edit the question to add the additional information. We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: I'm attempting to figure this out.

Comment: Thank you so much..mike yaworski :)..

Comment: Actually, when i am writing some random text in editText nd then clicking the add button,an OptionMenu appears but the text which i wrote in editText..it is not getting added into that optionsMenu :/ ..please help..would be really grateful ..

Comment: Mike, What is this 2352 ..new menu id .I didnt get this part..

Comment: Please comment on my answer. I don't get notified if you comment on your post. And it's just the id for the menu. When you create an id called like "addButton" that's actually the reference to the id but the actual value of the id is an `int`. So when checking which option is pressed, you would check if the id is `2352`. But 2352 is just a random number I typed; it could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, create a global `Menu` variable (outside of any method, but inside the class):

```
private Menu menu;
```

Then, in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`, assign that menu to be your menu, like so:

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    this.menu = menu; // here

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); // inflate your menu resource
    return true;
}
```

Then, you can use the [`.add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method to add the EditText text to your options menu, like so:

```
// in your Button click listener:
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
if (et.length() > 0) {
    int NEW_MENU_ID = 2352; // arbitrary number
    menu.add(0, NEW_MENU_ID, 0, et.getText().toString()); 
}
```

And then it's done.

Comment: @user3342854 go to http://pastie.org and paste all of your code there and then send me a link.

Comment: When i am clicking the add button,No options menu is displayed.

Comment: @user3342854 Please see my previous comment, or I can't help you anymore than I have. If you want the options menu to open when the button is clicked, use `openOptionsMenu();`

Comment: I want the Options Menu to be opened when the button is clicked,but the options menu should be containing the input from EditText. Usng openOptionsMenu(); it is just showing up a blank options menu.Please help me on this. and check the link. Thanks

Comment: 1. Are you sure the button click is being registered? Try making a toast pop up no matter what so that you know it's working. 2. You are calling `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` in the button click method... You need to change that to `openOptionsMenu();`

Comment: @user3342854 I just tested out your code and it's working for me. However, check my last comment out. Also, send me your XML file too.

Comment: Yes mike.I did write openOptionsMenu(); when i did it for the first time and It did open an Options menu for me,but Mike,this options menu is not containing any input which I gave in EditText...This is the only problem which is occuring now,else everything is fine..Dont worry about the xml file..A textview,an EditText and a button have been taken..and In the button,I wrote this line - <android:onClick= "add1" >

Comment: @user3342854 There's something that you're not telling me which is preventing this from working. I copied and pasted your code and it worked for me. The only thing I don't have is your XML, so I made one myself with `android:onClick="add1"` on a Button. I'm glad to continue to help if you have anymore questions, but it should be working. Keep me updating and please accept my answer if you get it working.